# GXT paging grid next and previous page

Tags: java, gxt

I'm trying to implement a paging grid in GXT 3 (following the example here: http://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/ui/widgets/grid/loading/GridLoadingRpc.html)

The example doesn't show on which event to update the state of the PagingLoadConfig object when next page / previous page are clicked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> The example doesn't show on which event to update the state of the PagingLoadConfig object when next page / previous page are clicked.

Whenever the next / previous page button clicked, it will automatically call the load method from the loader object. It is all automatically done by the Paging ToolBar component if we bind this component with our loader object. Take a look at this code that provide at sencha guide :

```
// Paging Tool Bar
PagingToolBar toolBar = new PagingToolBar(50);
toolBar.bind(pagingLoader);
```

Just make sure you bind the loader to Paging ToolBar component, and everything will be working like magic :-)